# How to find the continuity of a function at a given point

Tags: calculus

Given $f(x) = \begin {cases} \frac{(\sin x -x)}{x^c} & x\ne0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end {cases}$, how do I find all the constant $c$ such that the function is continuous. I tried deriving 
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{(\sin x -x)}{x^c}=0\\
\implies \lim_{x\to0} (\frac{\sin x}{x^c}) -(\frac{x}{x^c})=0\\
\implies \lim_{x\to0} (\frac{1}{x^{c-1}}) -(\frac{1}{x^{c-1}})=0$$
But this would only work for any $c\le1$. When I draw the graph, the function is continuous when $c\leq2$. Thus, I think my method is wrong. Please advise.

Comment: You've already tried to use L'Hopital's Rule?, I mean, derivate denominator and numerator of the quotient...

Comment: No, I have not tried that because I haven't learn the rule. Nevertheless, from what you have suggested, I am stuck at the denominator because I obtain $cx^{c-1}$ which is still an undefined denominator. Can I actually further proceed ?

Comment: $\lim \frac{\cos x -1}{cx^{c-1}} = \lim \frac{-2\sin^2(x/2)}{cx^{c-1}} = -\frac{2}{c}\lim \frac{(\sin^2 x/2)}{(x^2/4)}\frac{x^2/4}{x^{c-1}}$. This limit exists (and equals 0) only if $2 > c-1$ and hence if $c < 3$

Comment: I recommend you look up [asymptotic notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_notation). Also, be aware that it is a serious logical error to confuse big-O and little-O, and even worse to delete the error term of asymptotic expansions at any point. So beware answers with correct conclusions but incorrect arguments. To prove that $x - x^3/3! \le \sin(x) \le x - x^3/3! + x^5/5!$ for every real $x \ge 0$, repeatedly differentiate and use the mean value theorem together with the equality point at $x = 0$. You can then use this hard inequality to correctly analyze and solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just read big O ad little O recently. Will take the problem as an exercise.

Answer (score 2):

use this $$sin x= x- \frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...=\\ x- \frac{x^3}{3!}+x^5(\frac{1}{5!}-\frac{x^2}{7!}+...)=\\ x- \frac{x^3}{3!}+o(x^5)\\x\to 0 \implies sin x\sim x-\dfrac16x^3$$
so 
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{(\sin x -x)}{x^c}=0\\
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(x-\dfrac16 x^3 -x)}{x^c}=
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{-\dfrac16x^3}{x^c}=0 \implies c<3$$

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Nevertheless, I am not clear with the first and relatively the second equation. How can I derive $\sin x = x- \frac{x^3}{6}+o(x^5)$. Can you enlighten me please? In addition, what is notation $o$? complexity?

Comment: Alright, got it but I still need one more clarification. Can you explain why $\frac{x^5}{5!} - \frac{x^7}{7!}...$ is negligible/ignored, whereas $\frac{x^3}{3!}$ is kept in the second equation? I feel this is important to understand because it leads to the answer.